# Dask groupby unique as a frame - how to?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, dask

I have few dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

router = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '1', 5],
    ['2018-01-01 00:30:00', '1', 7],
    ['2018-01-01 01:00:00', '1', 25],
    ['2018-01-01 01:30:00', '1', 3],
    ['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2', 25],
    ['2018-01-01 00:30:00', '2', 7],
    ['2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2', 25],
    ['2018-01-01 01:30:00', '2', 35],
], columns=['time', 'cust_id', 'errors'])
router
```

[image]

```
devices = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '1', 'dev_1'],
    ['2018-01-01 00:30:00', '1', 'dev_1'],
    ['2018-01-01 00:30:00', '1', 'dev_2'],
    ['2018-01-01 01:00:00', '1', 'dev_1'],
    ['2018-01-01 01:00:00', '1', 'dev_2'],
    ['2018-01-01 01:00:00', '1', 'dev_3'],
    ['2018-01-01 01:30:00', '1', 'dev_2'],
    ['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2', 'dev_1'],
    ['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2', 'dev_2'],
    ['2018-01-01 00:30:00', '2', 'dev_1'],
    ['2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2', 'dev_2'],
    ['2018-01-01 01:00:00', '2', 'dev_3'],
    ['2018-01-01 01:30:00', '2', 'dev_2'],
    ['2018-01-01 01:30:00', '2', 'dev_4'],
], columns=['time', 'cust_id', 'device_id'])
devices
```

[image]

By using pandas, I can group by and calculate unique devices:

```
devices_per_time = devices.groupby(['cust_id', 'time'])['device_id'].unique().to_frame()
devices_per_time
```

[image]

I tried to do the same with dask:

[image]

I have the following questions:

1. how come that I cannot use devices.groupby(['cust_id', 'time'])['device_id'].unique()?
2. I manage to get the result, but I am not sure whether it is the optimal one. Can someone confirm that I am using dask in the proper way?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `.unique()` because it is still not implemented yet for dask series. Check the available functions: [`SeriesGroupby`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.groupby)

Here's another way of getting the result using parallel `apply` and `set`:

```
(devices
.groupby(['time','cust_id'])['device_id']
.apply(set, meta=object)
.apply(list,meta=object)
.compute()
.reset_index())
```

If you don't care about the final type (set or list), you can remove the `.apply(list,meta=object)`

Comment: On http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.groupby there is record: Series.nunique([split_every])  Return number of unique elements in the object. Why I cannot use that?